# Recursive formula $\pi_i = 2 \rho^i \pi_0$ with $\sum^4_{i=0} \pi_i =1$ yields $\pi_0 = \frac{1-\rho}{1+\rho-2\rho^5}$?

Tags: summation, recursion

The context doesn't really matter here. I'm stuck while doing an assignment. I have the following recursive formula:
$$\pi_i = 2 \rho^i \pi_0$$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Now I know that $\sum^4_{i=1} \pi_i =1$. In the solution it says that from this it follows that
$$\pi_0 (1 + \sum^4_{i=1} \rho^i) = 1$$ or $$\pi_0 \left(2 \frac{1-\rho^5}{1-\rho}\right) =1 .$$
i.e. $\pi_0 = \frac{1-\rho}{1+\rho-2\rho^5}$

I don't see how to obtain this result. What I have tried:
$$\pi_i = 2 \rho^i \pi_0$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^4 \pi_i = \sum_{i=0}^4 2 \rho^i \pi_0$$
$$1 = 2\pi_0 \left( \sum_{i=0}^4 \rho^i\right) = 2\pi_0 \left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty \rho^i -  \sum_{i=5}^\infty \rho^i \right) = 2\pi_0 \left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty \rho^i -  \sum_{i=0}^\infty \rho^5 \rho^i \right) = 2\pi_0 \left( \frac{1}{1-\rho} - \frac{\rho^5}{1-\rho}\right)$$

But from this is then follows that $\pi_0 = \frac{1-\rho}{2-2\rho^5}$. I'm not sure what I do wrong.

Comment: I think where you went wrong is in tacitly using the formula $\pi_i = 2\rho^i\pi_0$ for $i=0$ where it doesn't hold.